# Are there a plastic surgery conditions of a "double chin" or "triple chin"?

Tags: dermatology, injections, plastic-surgery, neck, chins

Executing `Is there a plastic surgery condition of a "double" or "triple" chin?` as a search query in three search engines (*Google*, *Bing*, *DuckDuckGo*) and looking at images brought me almost no results relevant results; most results in the first page where for "neck lift".

Searching "triple chin" alone shows me it is an informal term for a problem of neck fat causing three strains of fat from the neck to the chin.

Are there a plastic surgery conditions of a "double chin" or "triple chin"?
<sub>Note: I don't ask this for a personal medical or aesthetic problem but from curiosity and to broaden general knowledge only.</sub>

Comment: There must be; Because of cancer I have had a glossectomy . That surgery basically  involved extensive work on the front of my neck . After several years I have a wrinkle free neck with tight skin, at 80 yrs+. The surgeons must be able to do this without the  glossectomy .

Comment: `"Are there a plastic surgery conditions..."` -- This is very odd wording. Do you mean can plastic surgeons eliminate a double chin with surgery?

Comment: Unclear part omitted ; down voter is welcome to consider retracting down vote.